# Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\PermissionAlreadyExists : A `edit listing` permission already exists for guard `web`

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I have cloned [marketplace](https://github.com/marketplacekit/marketplacekit) repo and did the appropriate configurations. When I use `php artisan db:seed` i get this error

```
david@david-Lenovo-G50-30:~/projects/marketplacekit$ php artisan db:seed
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder
Seeding: RolesAndPermissionsSeeder

Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\PermissionAlreadyExists  : A `edit listing` permission already exists for guard `web`.

at /home/david/projects/marketplacekit/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Exceptions/PermissionAlreadyExists.php:11
 7| class PermissionAlreadyExists extends InvalidArgumentException
 8| {
 9|     public static function create(string $permissionName, string $guardName)
10|     {    
11|         return new static("A `{$permissionName}` permission already exists for guard`{$guardName}`.");
12|     }
13| }
14| 

  Exception trace:

1   Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\PermissionAlreadyExists::create("edit listing", "web")
  /home/david/projects/marketplacekit/vendor/spatie/laravel-permission/src/Models/Permission.php:42

2   Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission::create(["edit listing", "web"])
  /home/david/projects/marketplacekit/database/seeds/RolesAndPermissionsSeeder.php:20

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

**RolesandPermissionsSeeder.php**

```
    public function run(){

    //Reset cached roles and permissions
    app()['cache']->forget('spatie.permission.cache');

    //create permissions
    Permission::create(['name' => 'edit listing']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'publish listing']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'unpublish listing']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'disable listing']);
    Permission::create(['name' => 'ban user']);

   // create roles and assign created permissions

    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'member']);

    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'editor']);
    $role->givePermissionTo(['edit listing', 'publish listing', 'unpublish listing']);

    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'moderator']);
    $role->givePermissionTo(['edit listing', 'disable listing', 'publish listing', 'unpublish listing', 'ban user']);

    $role = Role::create(['name' => 'admin']);
    $role->givePermissionTo(Permission::all());

    $user = \App\Models\User::first();
    $user->assignRole('admin');
}
```

I have cleared user permissions and roles from cache both as a normal user and as root but its not helping. What am I doing wrong and how do I go about it?

Comment: Use `php artisan permission:cache-reset` on terminal or  `app()->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->forgetCachedPermissions();` on your seeder, as documented [here](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/cache/#manual-cache-reset)

Comment: It worked on my project

Comment: it also worked for me. thank you @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Hey @DanialNazari. Great, glad to have helped, and thanks for the feedback. I had forgotten this comment because I had not received any notification about it until now. If you mean the artisan command, you can upvote @suba 's answer, since the one I mentioned in my comment is just an alias of what Suba's answer says. If what you used is the `app()` helper, feel free to add an answer, since I don't see that option in any of the answers posted

Answer (score 13):

You can use artisan commands to clear spatie permission cache.

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache 
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused as a result of permissions previously cached. Running `php artisan cache:clear` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check , no have a twice rol assign

```
  $permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'companies.index'])->assignRole($role1);
$permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'companies.index'])->assignRole($role1);
```

You can check if you cache are clear

```
php artisan cache:forget spatie.permission.cache 
php artisan cache:clear
```